# How to set a particular child of horizontal scrollView as first visible child: Android

Tags: android, visibility, horizontalscrollview, childviews

I have 6 items/views in a horizontal scrollView, in an activity. {view1, view2, view3, view4, view5, view6} 
When i come to this activity, view1 is the the first visible item in the scrollview. But I would like to have view1, hidden and view2 to be the first to be visible. I still want it as a part of my scrollview items, so when i swipe left to right, it shows up as the first item.

Could someone please help me with this, so that I can get android to render the Horizontalscrollview such that first item visible is view2?

Thanks, 
Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to auto scroll it to the second position at rendering time. something like this-

```
// let x is distance , you want. you can scroll it like
            horiScrollView.scrollBy(-x, 0);
```

Comment: but + 10 would show that much of the first view right?

Comment: Also, should it not be a negative value, as i want it to scroll to the  left. I mean how does it know that i am  scrolling to the left or right

Comment: its just an example. you can use scrollBy